# How do I add a keyboard shortcut (enter) to my textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, button, overloading, eventargs

So I'm still very new to programming and I'm trying to create a program in which you'll enter a number (from 1-9 only) in a textbox and then clicking Enter instead of having to click on a button to have the number that I wrote on the textbox displayed on my second label. I keep getting two errors, the first throws off a

`No overload for 'textBox1_TextChanged' matches delegate
 'EventHandler'`

when I add `Key` to `EventArgs` (because `EventArgs` does not contain `Keycode`). The second is flags here:

```
this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label2_Click);
```

> "CS1061   'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'label2_Click' and
>   no extension method 'label2_Click' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)"

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tarea7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                label2.Text = textBox1.ToString();
            }
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debes de escribir un numero de 1-9");
                textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            }   
        }

        private void label2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Errors are self describing. `TextChanged` event doesn't accept `KeyEventArgs`. Also You don't have `label2_Click` method in your class.

Comment: You don't need to handle `TextChanged` event. Put a `Button` on your form and handle `Click` event of button and do what you need in button click event handler. Then it's enough to set the button as value of `AcceptButton` property of your form. This way, when you enter, the code of your button will execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm taking a course and it says I should use a label and no buttons. I tried changing 'TextChanged' to 'KeyPress' and 'KeyDown' since it doesn't support 'KeyEventArgs' but I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add `textBox1_KeyDown` event to your `textBox1.KeyDown` event at visual designer or at the file Form1.designer.cs:

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

Then add following function to your code. When user type a number from 1 - 9 and press Enter, it will be copied to `label2`.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1)
                {
                    char tbChar = textBox1.Text[0];
                    if (tbChar >= '1' && tbChar <= '9')
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Correct");
                        label2.Text = tbChar.ToString();

                        // Clear textbox
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                        return;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Your input is not a number from 1 - 9");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Also, you don't need this line, remove it:

```
this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label2_Click);
```